# a crawler using php and Regex

Tags: php, regex

i wanna a regex to capture any thing between `<h1>` and `<br />` into **matches['name']**. 
and any thing between `<h1 style="float: left;">` and `</h2>` to **matches['cost']**.
how i should do it ?

Cheers,

Comment: Do not use regular expressions for this. Use a proper HTML parser. Also, your request doesn't seem to make much sense - do you really want the data between these non-matching tags?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

Comment: @Pekka For particular purposes regexps are easier way to go.

Comment: yes i want this ! and want regex too !

Comment: How many non-matching tag did you expect to find? Is this a common feature on the page you're parsing?

Comment: The <center> cannot hold! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1):

This is not an HTML parser, it's just a regex based string search ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/5JAjfp)):

```
$searches = array(
    'name' => '<h1>(.*)<br />',
    'cost' => '<h1 style="float: left;">(.*)</h2>'
);

$matches = array();
foreach($searches as $name => $pattern)
{
    $r = preg_match_all("~{$pattern}~", $str, $matches[$name]);
    $matches[$name] = $matches[$name][1];
}

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  name1
            [1] =>  name2
        )

    [cost] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  cost1
            [1] =>  cost1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/<h1 style="float: left;">(?P<cost>.*?)<\/h1>.*<h1>(?P<name>.*?)<br \/>/s', $string, $matches);

echo $matches['name'];
echo $matches['cost'];
```

Comment: thanks I want some thing same to Your answer ! but in doesent work when i teted with this :
$string='<div id="bodyContent" class="grid_16 push_4"> 
 
<form name="cart_quantity" action="http://iran-micro.com/product_info.php/products_id/1407/action/add_product" method="post"> 
<div> 
  <h1 style="float: left;">xxxxxxxxxxx</h1> 
  <h1>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr<br /><span class="smallText">zzzzzzzzzz</span></h1> 
</div> 
 ' ;

Comment: <?php
$data='<div id="bodyContent" class="grid_16 push_4"> 
 
<form name="cart_quantity" action="http://iran-micro.com/product_info.php/products_id/1407/action/add_product" method="post"> 
<div> 
  <h1 style="float: left;">xxxxxxxxxxx</h1> 
  <h1>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr<br /><span class="smallText">zzzzzzzzzz</span></h1> 
</div> 
 ' ;

preg_match('/<h1 style="float: left;">(?P<cost>.*?)</h1>.*?<h1>(?P<name>.*?)<br />/s', $data, $matches);

echo $matches['name'];
echo $matches['cost'];

?>        dont show any thing yet !!! :((

Comment: @sataho You made a bad copy of my script :) It seems that you removed some backslashes.

Comment: thanks a lot. can you send me a .php version of this program that works correct ? 
littlejardin@yahoo.com

Comment: @sataho The code in my answer is a working code. Full version: `<?php $data='<div id="bodyContent" class="grid_16 push_4"> <form name="cart_quantity" action="iran-micro.com/product_info.php/products_id/1407/action/…; method="post"> <div> <h1 style="float: left;">xxxxxxxxxxx</h1> <h1>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr<br /><span class="smallText">zzzzzzzzzz</span></h1> </div> ' ; preg_match('/<h1 style="float: left;">(?P<cost>.*?)<\/h1>.*<h1>(?P<name>.*?)<br \/>/s', $data, $matches); echo $matches['name']; echo $matches['cost']; ?>`